# Laravel Ajax - Uncaught ReferenceError: KWS1389776 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have an AJAX call to fetch a record in model and display values in a modal that must popup after GET request is done.

The javascript console is returning `Uncaught ReferenceError: KWS1389776 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

It looks some issue in how the variable is passed to javascript function in `onClick` event.

This is the code developed:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-label-primary btn-lg btn-upper" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#kt_modal_4_2" 
onClick="getPropertyDetails({{$match->prop_id}})">
{{ __('pages/processes/offerdemand.labels.matchs.index.button.viewproperty') }}</button>
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Property;

class PropertyController extends Controller
{
    public function details($id)
    {
        $property = Property::where('prop_id', $id)->first();
        return view('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.propertymodal', compact('property'));
    }
}
```

```
function getPropertyDetails(prop_id) {
    console.log(prop_id);

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/property/details/' + prop_id,

        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            if (data.status != 200) {

                console.log(data.status);
                swal.fire({
                    "title": "",
                    "text": "Ocurrió un error, contactar al administrador",
                    "type": "error",
                    showConfirmButton: !1,
                    timer: 3000,
                    onClose: () => {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });

            }
            $('#kt_modal_4_2').modal("show");


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing it a variable, no?

You need to wrap the input as a string e.g.

```
onClick="getPropertyDetails('{{ $match->prop_id }}')">
```

At this point, I can only assume that your `prop_id` is `KWS1389776`, and the error has come up because the reference to it as a variable does not exist, as the error states.